# Changing rhinoslider direction after init

Tags: jquery, setting

I am trying to change the direction of jQuery Rhinoslider after each animation. I think it's just a matter of changing the `slideNextDirection` setting, but I don't know too much about the jQuery plugin structure and how to get at that setting.
This is what I tried, but obviously it doesn't work:

```
$slider = $('#slider').rhinoslider({
    slideNextDirection: 'toTop',
    callBackNext: function() {
        $(this).slideNextDirection = 'toLeft';
        //tried this too :)
        //$slider.slideNextDirection = 'toLeft';
        return false;
    }
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To change the settings on the fly isn't possible. But you can uninit Rhinoslider and call it afterwards with your changes. See: http://rhinoslider.com/api/external-calls-of-internal-functions/

In version 1.1 coming in a few weeks you can also set the slide to start.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. This is a one off thing that someone needed quickly, so I've tweaked the plugin core to solve this. I know, I know, I'm a terrible person :)

I just altered the `direction` variable conditionally in the `slide()` method.

Thanks for a great piece of code, I'm sure I will be using it more in the future!

Comment: Perfect, that you found a solution for your problem.
This is what we have suggested next. But for this solution you need some knowledge of Javascript